# Correlation parameter with small nonlinear sample like hour / day of week?

Tags: time-series, correlation, pearson-r, seasonality, spearman-rho

I have a dataset of magnitudes Y which gives the scale / magnitude of some event. Each event is also timestamped:

```
Y = [(time1,mag1), (time2,mag2),...]
```

I want to see, for example, if magnitudes are coordinated with a specific day of week or hour of day.

I am familiar with Pearson and Spearman correlation. However, these tell you whether a series of data Y is monotonically correlated with some other series X. In this case, it would only be useful in telling me if Y is monotonically increasing/decreasing throughout the week. I guess one could permute the possible permutations:

```
M T W T F S S
M W T .....
```

And compute the correlation for each permutation, but this grows unscalable quickly. What is the closest parameter that I could use for non-linear correlation (for this problem)?

Comment: Are all the magnitudes from the same study unit measured repeatedly over time, or are these N different units & the time of measurement just happens to have been recorded as well?

Comment: The events could have occurred at any time (magnitude can be 0 for long stretches of time), for example, earthquakes (I am not doing anything with weather, just an example of this).

Comment: Would they be earthquakes in the same place? What matters is if they are on the same study unit.

Comment: Same study unit yes, sorry.

Comment: It seems that you are interested in marked point process $[T_i,\,
Y_i]$.  Since your interest seems to be on the marks $Y_i$ you could simply
use a parametric model with time indicators as regressors.
For instance, you can use a GLM with hour as regressor in a gaussian
or gamma regression.